# image save to memorystream exif format

Tags: c#, system.drawing

When i save an image to an memoriestream in Exif Format i get an ArgumentNullException, Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.Parametername: encoder
Here is my code:

```
        Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\tkaemmerling\Pictures\alpha-test-photo.jpg");

        image.Save(@"C:\Users\tkaemmerling\Pictures\alpha-test-photo.Exif", ImageFormat.Exif);
        using (MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(memstream, ImageFormat.Exif);

        }
```

How can i save the image in exif format to an memory stream?

Comment: I don't quite understand why u save the image as file and then into the stream. what if try to remove the image.Save(fileNamePath) before saving it into the stream?

Comment: The same error happens this is just some code from a testaplication where i tryed to save the Image as picture and as memorystream.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't think it works even for saving file on disk. If you open the saved file it has PNG in the header. If you check the internals, the save method looks like this:

```
public void Save(string filename, ImageFormat format)
{
    if (format == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("format");
    }
    ImageCodecInfo imageCodecInfo = format.FindEncoder();
    if (imageCodecInfo == null)
    {
        imageCodecInfo = ImageFormat.Png.FindEncoder();
    }
    this.Save(filename, imageCodecInfo, null);
}
```

Problem is there is no encoder associated with the EXIF format - try debugging

```
var imageEncoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
```

So you may as well use

```
    Image image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\tkaemmerling\Pictures\alpha-test-photo.jpg");

    image.Save(@"C:\Users\tkaemmerling\Pictures\alpha-test-photo.Exif", ImageFormat.Png);
    using (MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(memstream, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```